# An isomorphism between the dual space of a Hilbert space and a larger space containing the same Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $G \subset H \subset F$ be three Hilbert spaces such that the smaller ones are continuously and densely embedded into the larger ones. Furthermore, assume
$$|\langle h, g\rangle_H|\le \|h\|_{F}\|g\|_G,$$
for all $h\in H$ and $v\in G$.

Define a mapping from $F$ to $G^*$ (the continuous dual space of $G$),
$$(Jf) (g):= \lim_{n\to \infty} \langle h_n, g \rangle_H,$$
where $h_n \to f$ in $\|\cdot\|_F$.

I believe that $J$ is an isometric isomorphim between $F$ and $G^*$ (i.e. a bijective mapping preserving norm).

It is easy to show that $J$ is well-defined (not dependent on the converging sequence) and $\|Jf\|_{G^*} \le \|f\|_F$. How to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $G=H=F$ and the embedding map being for $i_1: G\to H$ multiplication with $\frac12$ and for $i_2:H\to F$ just the identity. Then your condition is 
$$|\langle h, i_1(g)\rangle| =\frac12 |\langle h, g\rangle|≤ \|h\|\,\|g\|,$$
which is satisfied.

What is $J$? Note that $Jf(g)=\frac12 \langle f,g\rangle$, so $J$ is not an isometry. But $J$ is topologically an isomorphism, in fact this is always true.

Consider a general scenario as sketched in your question:

Note that $J$ is injective, for if $Jf(g)=0$ for all $g$ then $\langle h_n, g\rangle_H\to0$ for all $g$ and and $\|h_n\|_H\to 0$ since $G$ has dense image in $H$, then by continuity of the embedding $H\to F$ you get $\|h_n\|_F\to0$ so $f=0$.

Next suppose there is a $g\in G$ so that $Jf(g)=0$ for all $f\in F$. In particular you get that $\langle h, g\rangle_H =0$ for all $h\in H$ which implies that $g=0$. Thus the orthogonal complement of the image of $J$ is zero, and $J$ is surjective.

By the open mapping theorem $J$ is a topological isomorphism.

Comment: If the embeddings are the canonical ones (identical mapping), then $J$ is indeed an isometric one?

Comment: Yes, then $J$ is the canonical isomorphism $G\to G^*$.

Comment: $G \to G^*$ or $F \to G^*$? What is the canonical isomorphism $F \to G^*$?

Comment: If all embeddings are the identity mapping then $G=H=F$. The canonical isomorphism $G\to G^*$ is $v\mapsto (w\mapsto \langle v,w\rangle)$. As an aside note that this (and $J$ as well) is anti-linear, ie $J(\lambda f)= \overline{\lambda} Jf$.

Comment: Consider weighted sequence spaces $H = \{(f_k)_{k}: \sum_k f_k^2 < \infty\}$, $G = \{(f_k)_{k}: \sum_k f_k^2 k^2< \infty\}$, and $F = \{(f_k)_{k}: \sum_k f_k^2 /k^2< \infty\}$. This triple satisfies the condition but $G \subsetneq H \subsetneq F$.

Comment: Very well, here you are looking at subspaces of a certain vector space and giving these subspaces _different_ scalar products. If you want take the example I have above but give $H$ the scalar product $\frac12 \langle ,\rangle$ and have all mappings be identity, you will then get the same map $J: F\to G^*$.

Comment: In this case can $J$ be shown to be isometry?

Comment: Yes. Your case is the same as $G'=H'=F'=\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ and letting the map $i_1:G'\to H'$ be $i_1( (f_n)_n) = (f_n/n)_n$ and $i_2: H'\to F'$ the same map. I would like to call the map $A=i_1=i_2$, since its a nicer letter to work with. First note that $A$ is a hermitian map. Now $Jf(g) = \lim \langle h_n, Ag\rangle$, where $h_n\in H'$ is so that $A(h_n)\to f$. Since $A$ is hermitian you have $Jf(g) = \lim \langle h_n, Ag \rangle = \lim \langle Ah_n, g\rangle = \langle f,g\rangle$ and you recover the canonical isomorphsim $\ell^2\to (\ell^2)^*$.